# 12.04 installation failure -> failed to boot -> system showing grub rescue

Tags: 12.04, boot, grubrescue

I had initially installed 12.10 for some project related SCiM-m17n . Unfortunately scim-m17n was not working (raised in askubutu too) . I was advised by my client to install 12.04 where this is working perfectly .

I chose the option for erasing 12.10 and install 12.04 . Installation was going smooth until it suddenly stopped saying some problem in CD .

Since then machine is going to grub rescue prompt - I am unable to boot even in windows .

I have tried those SET prefix , root steps but it is unable to recognize boot command .

Can someone please advise me urgently how to boot the machine in Windows at least .

Comment: Ask Ubuntu is large "staffed" by unpaid volunteers. Since you seem to be installing Ubuntu for commercial reasons and have "urgent" requirements, you may be better off signing up for paid support from Canonical.

Comment: Does this guarantee that I shall get necessary help ? Is there any SLA ? Are you saying that we can raise problems here only related to personal usage of ubuntu ?

Comment: I'm saying there is a more appropriate way to get "urgent" help.

Comment: Thanks a lot Vasa . I shall explore that part as I have many other queries related to ubuntu for this project . Shall be grateful if someone can provide this help for the time being .

Answer (score 0):

If you want to proceed to install ubuntu and the CD problem exists then you can make a bootable usb using unetbootin or LinuxLive usb creator. These softwares run both in Ubuntu and windows. After making an usb bootable, plug it and boot from the LiveUSB. The installation process is same as before. This process is much faster than CDs.
If you want to continue to windows, then insert your windows installation CD/DVD and boot from it. You will find a repair option at lower left corner of the installation window.
Or manually after booting into windows installation wizard choose command prompt and try these commands:

**bootrec.exe /fixmbr**

**bootrec.exe /fixboot**

hope this helps